# Descendants() with a parameter returns empty result

Tags: c#, xml, linq

With the following XML in XElement `hwLibs`.

```
<ConnectedHardwareLibraries xmlns="CBOpenIFSchema3_0">
    <ConnectedHardwareLibrary Name="BasicHwLib" MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="0" Revision="0" FilePath="HWLibraries:" />
    <ConnectedHardwareLibrary Name="CI854PROFIBUSHwLib" MajorVersion="2" MinorVersion="11" Revision="40" FilePath="HWLibraries:" />
</ConnectedHardwareLibraries>
```

I wish to get the library element with the attribute `Name="CI854PROFIBUSHwLib"`.

```
<ConnectedHardwareLibrary Name="CI854PROFIBUSHwLib" MajorVersion="2" MinorVersion="11" Revision="40" FilePath="HWLibraries:" />
```

With the following query the expected result is rendered.

```cs
IEnumerable<XElement> x =
    from item in hwLibs.Descendants()
    where item.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("CI854PROFIBUSHwLib")
    select item;
```

But the following returns an empty result.

```cs
IEnumerable<XElement> x =
    from item in hwLibs.Descendants("ConnectedHardwareLibrary")
    where item.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("CI854PROFIBUSHwLib")
    select item;
```

Why?

Comment: You need to look for a namespace : xmlns="CBOpenIFSchema3_0".  The following returns nothing : Descendants("ConnectedHardwareLibrary")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample XML document has a default namespace of "CBOpenIFSchema3_0". That means all elements of the document will have that namespace, if not specified otherwise.

So that is why when you use the `Descendants` method specifying a parameter containing a local element name of "ConnectedHardwareLibrary" with no namespace, that will not match anything.

You can change your code to query with an element name including the namespace as follows:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> x =
    from item in hwLibs.Descendants("{CBOpenIFSchema3_0}ConnectedHardwareLibrary")
    where item.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("CI854PROFIBUSHwLib")
    select item;
```

Alternatively, there are a couple of other different syntax's which do the same thing:

```
XNamespace ns = "CBOpenIFSchema3_0";
IEnumerable<XElement> x =
    from item in hwLibs.Descendants(ns + "ConnectedHardwareLibrary")
    where item.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("CI854PROFIBUSHwLib")
    select item;
```

```
IEnumerable<XElement> x =
    from item in hwLibs.Descendants(XName.Get("ConnectedHardwareLibrary","CBOpenIFSchema3_0")
    where item.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("CI854PROFIBUSHwLib")
    select item;
```